# How can i load existing page?

Tags: c#, wpf

I work a lot of page. When i return the previous page, code reset the page. I want to see previous page. How can i this?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{     
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void BtnClickP1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Content = new KK();
    }

    private void BtnClickP2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Content = new AIRFOIL();
    }

    private void BtnClickP3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Content = new OB();
    }
}
```

I use new command for every tab page. I think it is wrong. I want to see existing page when i push button. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use variable if you want to store the modification in the page.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private KK _kkPage;
    private AIRFOIL _airfoilPage;
    private OB _obPage;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _kkPage = new KK();
        _airfoilPage = new AIRFOIL();
        _obPage = new OB();
    }


    private void BtnClickP1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Content = _kkPage;
    }

    private void BtnClickP2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Content = _airfoilPage;
    }

    private void BtnClickP3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Content = _obPage;
    }
}
```